# Send a single data asynchronously from one project to another project

Tags: c#

How we can send a simple data (for example "mango") from one windows project to another windows project using C# - asynchronously?

Here is the client code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Socket _clientSocket;
    private byte[] _buffer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 
        3333), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        _clientSocket.EndConnect(AR);
    }       

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        _clientSocket.EndSend(AR);
        _buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Click("MANGO");                     
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Click("GRAPES");            
    }

    public void Click(string xmlstring)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] xmlbuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlstring);
             _clientSocket.BeginSend(xmlbuffer, 0, xmlbuffer.Length, 
             SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And Server code is,

```
  public partial class Server : Window
  {
    private Socket _serversocket, _clientSocket;
    private byte[] _buffer;

    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartServer();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }        

    private void StartServer()
    {
        _serversocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _serversocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3333));
        _serversocket.Listen(0);
        _serversocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        _clientSocket = _serversocket.EndAccept(AR);
        _buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, 
         SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
        _serversocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), 
        null);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        int received = _clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer); // here get ans
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
    }
}
```

when i click button1, the word "mango" should get in the server side. when i click button2, the word "grapes" should get in the server side.

when i first click on the button1, it will work and i am getting the "mango" in the server side. but second time when click on the button2, nothing happens - the word "grapes" is not getting in the server side.

Please help to get it right.

Comment: In the receive event you need a begin receive to get another message and in the send event you need a beginsend.  See msdn example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `_clientSocket.BeginReceive` in the end of `ReceiveCallback`.